# How can i transfer audio in in my face book app in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an Android application. Here I'm integrating the facebook api to my application.
Now I want to send audio to friends who are in the chat list. My audio files are located on the sdcard. I tried to send the files using asmack api but i did not get success.

Please advise me is the any solution for my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted any code snippets.

The FB chat is based on XMPP protocol and you can check the official [Facebook Chat API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/).

Currently facebook does not allow file transfers. The only data you can send and receive are

- Plain-text messages (not HTML messages)
- Typing notifications using the XEP-0085 protocol extension (not the XEP-0022 extension)
- vCards using the XEP-0054 extension
- Friends' photos (either with vCard or XMPP presence)

That means you cannot do what you are looking for currently.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information. In my app i want to share image, audio. Could you please provide me a code sample to transfer image like Friends' photos (either with vCard or XMPP presence).Thanks in advance.